# Disable database related autoconfigurations in integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I wanted to get rid of spring datasource related configuration from my test YAML file.

I have an integration test case annotated with @SpringBootTest. When this test case runs, it auto-configures the database-related configuration, including JDBC Template and Spring Data. This test case has its own YAML configuration.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class myIntgTest{
 
}
```

I've attempted to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration and HibernateJPAAutoConfiguration using @EnableAutoConfiguration and spring.autoconfigure.exclude, but neither of these methods is working. Unfortunately, I can't use @MockBean or @Profile on my application configuration because of some inter-dependencies.

Could someone please assist me in preventing the loading of these database-related configurations when my integration test case runs? This way, I don't have to include datasource-related details in my test YAML file.

Thank you in advance.

Tried exclude option using @EnableAutoConfiguration, spring.autoconfigure.exclude, @MockBean and @Profile, @TestPropery, @ComponentScan.